# Struts Exception

Tags: java, jsp, struts2

an error in my jsp file, I'm using struts

```
<%@taglib uri="/struts-tags" prefix="s"%>
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<s:url namespace="/" action="produits"></s:url>
<s:a href="%{lien1}">Produits</s:a>
</body>
</html>
```

This is the message which I receive when I execute my script:

> the file "/struts-tags" not found

Comment: Did you add the struts2-core-.jar to the libraries of the project? If you did, clean the project.

Comment: yuup i do .. how can i clean the project !!

Comment: With Project → Clean.

Comment: thank you bro .. the problem is still existe .. which version of struts2-core.jar I have to include ?!

Comment: you can include the struts2-core-2.3.20.jar (latest jar at the time of writing) in your WEB-INF\lib folder.

Comment: How were you using struts *without* the core file?!

Comment: sir dave, I have made an error in the location of the core :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Include the `struts2-core-2.3.20.jar` (latest jar at the time of writing) in your `WEB-INF\lib` folder. And clean the project.